# File Input/output Stream for MP4 videos

Tags: java, stream, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I want to read & write mp4 file through my java code. here is my code to read 2 file and merge it. it is working fine for text file but not for mp4 files. here it is reading both files properly but problem is while writing the file. Help me in merging the 2 video files:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Stm4
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean q=true;
        FileInputStream fis=null;
        FileInputStream dis=null;
        SequenceInputStream uiu=null;
        FileOutputStream sis=null;
        try
        {
            System.out.print("enter the first file");
            String s=input.next();          
            System.out.print("enter the second file");
            String p=input.next();
            System.out.print("enter the destination File name");
            String u=input.next();
            fis=new FileInputStream(s);
            dis=new FileInputStream(p);
            uiu=new SequenceInputStream(fis,dis);
            sis=new FileOutputStream(u);
            int a;
            do
            {
                a=uiu.read();
                if(a==-1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                sis.write(a);
            }
            while(true);
            fis.close();
            dis.close();
            sis.close();
            uiu.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ime)
        {
            System.out.print("file not found");
        }
        catch(IOException jnf)
        {
            System.out.print("file is empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mp4 files can't be concatenated like that. You probably want something like: https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser

Answer (score 0):

Just joining the binary data will not help you to create a valid video output.
You should search for a library which can handle video editing or you have to follow the mp4 spec for your output video.

MP4 spec:
http://jchblog.u.qiniudn.com/doc/ISO_IEC_14496-14_2003-11-15.pdf